# Can you have multiple Approvals in Azure DevOps Environments

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

#### Context

I'm deploying multiple apps using Azure Pipelines to app dedicated namespace in a single AKS cluster.

#### Problem

Since my ADO Environments is assigned to a single AKS cluster, and when I add `Approvals and cheks` for that environment, then every `Deployment` that points to that environment will need approval. This is problematic when you deploy multiple apps per environment because all  deployments will be guarded by this policy.

#### Question

Besides of creating approvals for Environment per app. Is there a way of setting up a granularity of approvals within ADO Environments?

Answer (score 1):

#### Short Answer

"No". At the moment of writing this answer, an environment in DevOps supports only one approval -maybe it will change in the future.

#### Solution

There is a workaround for this problem. You can set approvals for individual `service connection` instead.

When you deploy an application to an individual namespace, a service connection is automatically created for that namespace. It might look like this `<aks-cluster-name>-<k8s-namespace>-<long-intiger-id>` e.g. *my-aks-dev-we-sandbox-1654784698962*. You just need to find this service connection in `ADO's Project settings`, click it, and then click on three dots (located in right upper corner) and choose `Approvals and checks`. This way, you will be able to control who should do the approvals.